# Jquery autocomplete split arabic text

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using [Jquery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) plug-in for dictionary purposes, everthing is fine with English-Pashto translation while Pashto-English auto-suggestion causes some issues with string. It make parts of some words mentioned below

[image]

While the real word is ملاحظہ
is there anything to be tune in .js files, i mentioned arabic in question to make some sense to non-Pashto speakers.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem as u
with some tweaking it got worked
 First :
try to keep all ur connection with database , php and css in UTF8

Second : if ur searching for long strings try to divide them into smaller chunks in database

look at this link it might help too
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-autocomplete-special-character-encoding